# Sliding to different pages in website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using `Zurb Foundation` to create a small website and I have a top navigation bar with four links.
 On clicking each link, I want to *horizontally slide to a different page* every time.

The content in the page should be loaded via ajax and not loading all pages on visiting index page itself. 
(note: content for slide-to page should be loaded not after the slide animation but somehow with the slide itself or else the empty sliding would look a little weird)

In addition, since I am using foundation to get responsive layouts, I am confused how to place the sections for the different pages horizontally.  If the website wouldn't have been responsive, I probably would have placed the other pages separated by a margin property and to slide them, I could have done an `animate` of the margin property.

But, how do I get a horizontal page sliding effect (along with ajax loading) on my current page?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a 'single page website'? There are a lot of tutorials about this but this one is great:

http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/single-page-sliding-nav/

A live demo can be found here:

http://vandelaydesign.com/demos/single-page/

This uses jquery to scroll to the element with a specific id on the page. When you click one of the menu items it scrolls/slides automatically to that part of the page.

Just because the code is a bit long I'll only post the Jquery, to give you an idea.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#topnav').onePageNav({
    currentClass: 'current',
      scrollOffset: 0
  });
});
</script>

$('#nav').onePageNav({
    currentClass: 'current',
    changeHash: false,
    scrollSpeed: 750,
    scrollOffset: 30,
    scrollThreshold: 0.5,
    filter: '',
    easing: 'swing',
    begin: function() {
        //I get fired when the animation is starting
    },
    end: function() {
        //I get fired when the animation is ending
    },
    scrollChange: function($currentListItem) {
        //I get fired when you enter a section and I pass the list item of the section
    }
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I could have done the sliding here with jQuery as well, but I am using foundation here which has a fixed grid layout and I can't place elements outside the grid layout. Btw, I forgot to mention that I want to do horizontal slide. I'l edit my post to add this

Comment: Do you have an live example of your page?

Comment: Here's one inbuilt example on Foundation's website which has pretty much similar layout to mine :https://www.notableapp.com/posts/a4d0d0833043bcddf1cb4a810112bb85e379bd44#annotate

Comment: Something like this? http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/WebsiteScrolling/ (scrolling effect)

Comment: Precisely. Using foundation, I have 12 column grid and if I place elements (`four horizontal divs in my case`) which in total have greater width than 12 column grid, then some of the `div` section would automatically move into the next row. In essence, I am not seeing a solution to the horizontal placement of `divs` in foundation, where I could animate to using jquery